# Missing Nuget service end point in TFS 2017.1

Tags: tfs-2017

When I am trying to create a Nuget Service endpoint which should be used in Build Definition, I am not getting the Nuget option in the list. 

TFS Version: 2017 update 1 On-Prem

License: Enterprise and its made default

URL: http://mytfs:8080/tfs/collection/project/_admin/_services?_a=resources

When I try in VSTS project I get it in the drop down but it's not listed in TFS on Prem. Please help me if I am missing anything here or do I need to `perform/configure` my on-prem environment with anything to make Nuget option list under  Service endpoint list.

Please let me know for more details and appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately for **on-premise TFS** the `Nuget service endpoint` was added after TFS 2017 Update 3, it's available starting from TFS 2018.

So, you cannot see the `Nuget service endpoint` in TFS 2017 Update1, if you insist on using it, then you can upgrade to TFS 2018 or migrate to VSTS.

Answer (score 0):

As it is not added before 2017 Update 3, you can use a `Generic Connection`. `Server URL` is the nuget url, and the api key is the `Password/Token Key`.

If your company would not like to update TFS you can use it.